# How to disable default Spring security with Spring boot?

Tags: spring, security

I use Spring boot 2 and Spring security but I can't disable the default security. This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
```

Comment: You need to exclude security auto configuration: `@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: thank you zakaria amine for your answer. My problem is resolved

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you have to exclude the security auto configuration with:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```